# How to use SQLiteJDBC library (sqlite-jdbc-crypt) with encryption

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, cryptography

I user this lib guide https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt for creating encrypted database.
I have in classpath the dependency of that lib:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.willena</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.31.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Following the guide from that link:

I create database file using next code:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:file:C:/Bin/db/sqllite_crypto/database?cipher=chacha20&key=myEncryptionKey";
String user = "user";
String password = "password";
final Connection connection = DriverManager.
        getConnection(url, user, password);
```

But when  I check the database file, it's not encrypted! (I'm able to find inserted data using a notepad).
What I do wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue was, I had another sqlite library(that doesn't support encryption) in classpath that took precedence.
But we definitely found some strange behavior if the username\pasword is defined:
https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt/issues/14